# I want to join two strings, but separate the two strings by a space

Tags: python-3.x

I want to process files quickly through a program called star, but I have many files and want to pre-format the input from my files to save time. The format required is-

`sample1read1.fq, sample2read1.fq \space\ sample1read2.fq, sample2read2.fq`

[EDIT]: My files look like this:

`trimmed_Sample_RX.fq`  where X can either be 1 or 2.

Star wants me to load all of the R1's together, separated by a comma, then a space and then all of my R2's together separated by a comma. To tackle this problem I have attempted to use the join command in python:

```
def identifier(x):
   return(x[-10:])

read1= list(sorted(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(PATH),'*_R1.fq'), key= identifier))
read1.append(' ')
read2= list(sorted(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(PATH),'*_R2.fq'), key= identifier))

first_half= ','.join(read1)
second_half= ','.join(read2)
star_input= first_half + second_half
print(star_input)= 'trimmed_sample1R1.fq,trimmed_sample2R1.fq, , trimmed_sample1R2.fq,trimmed_sample2R2.fq'
```

I attempt to add a space to the end of my file list read1. Then I turn everything into a string and attempt to join the two strings together, but that space I added into my first half pops up in the concatenation as a comma

```
'trimmed_sample1R1.fq,trimmed_sample2R1.fq, , trimmed_sample1R2.f,trimmed_sample2R2.fq'
```

If I remove the step where I append a blank space and then concatenate the two strings I get the following

```
'trimmed_sample1R1.fq,trimmed_sample2R1.fqtrimmed_sample1R2.fq,trimmed_sample2R2.fq'
```

So now the comma is gone, but I also lose the space.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that between "sample2read1.fq" and "sample1read2.fq" there are three spaces?

Comment: Between sample2read1.fq and sample1read2.fq there I get two spaces on either side of the comma. I want to remove the comma and have just one blank space between both halves so that the input looks like the program wants.

Comment: Can you provide the files directly please? I am not sure of your explainations. So I can write you a snippet

Comment: @VincentBénet I have tried to further explain the problem with an edit. Is this more clear?

Comment: Maybe not a clean approach but you could do it by something `y = x.split(",")
p = []
for i in y:
    e = i + ", "
    p.append(e)
print("".join(p))`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround, but if there is a better way to do this please point it out to me. Basically I kept my code the same, but I change the last step. Now the flow looks like this:

```py
first_half=','.join(read1)
second_half=','.join(read2)
star_input= '{} {}'.format(first_half, second_half)
print(star_input)
```

```
'trimmed_sample1R1.fq,trimmed_sample2R1 trimmed_sample1R2.fq,trimmedsample2R2.fq'
```